# How to perfom a $in where condition with Ecto and Mongodb Adapter?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to perform a `$in` condition in a where clause using [mongodb ecto adapter](https://github.com/michalmuskala/mongodb_ecto/tree/ecto-2.1) without success:

```
iex(2)> Hookshot.Hook.with_events([1, 2]) |> Hookshot.Repo.all
** (Ecto.Query.CastError) web/models/hook.ex:63: value `[1, 2]` in `where` cannot be cast to type {:in, {:array, :string}} in query:

from h in Hookshot.Hook,
  where: h.events in ^[1, 2],
  select: h

    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1325: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
      (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:122: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
      (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:35: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
       (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:182: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/6
       (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:175: IEx.Evaluator.do_eval/4
       (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:155: IEx.Evaluator.eval/4
```

Implementation in the model:

```
def with_events(query \\ Hook, events) do
  from h in query,
    where: h.events in ^events
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is `events` defined with type `{:array, :string}`? Try `events = Enum.map(events, &to_string/1)` before the query.

Comment: You are using Ecto 2.1. There has not been much work done on bringing the mongo ecto adapter up to the most recent version. It is possible that it just does not work yet.

Comment: @Dogbert yes the field is defined with `field :events, {:array, :string}, default: []`

Comment: @Dogbert same issue with a list of strings